# Disallow editing on linked (referenced) items

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Recently I've found how to add a link to an item in Visual Studio so that you can reference common or shared files between projects. Editing the original propagates the changes to the projects where the file is referenced. But you can also edit the reference item and the changes are reflected in the original file, is there a way to prevent this behavior?

Comment: What are you trying to do and why?

Comment: I want to create a "master" project that I can reference items from (ie. the login screen) in other projects. I want to be able to edit the items in the "master" project but not in the child projects (I know it's not inheritance).
This would let me make changes to only the "master" project and see the reflected changes in the children. But I want to prevent editing  (accidental or otherwise) from the children projects

Comment: Why not just reference the master project and use its classes?

Comment: Would that be done through Project -> Add Reference...?
It seems that I can only add components from previous projects, however I want to share forms and vb classes.

Comment: You could make those forms and classes public in the “common” project, and then reference this project via “Projects” tab in Add Reference dialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reference item *is* the original file.
If you don't want “the original” to change, copy the file instead of referencing it.

Also, people *like* editing files.
If some code is not supposed to be edited, make it a binary.